# Alinhamento Boostrap

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Pessoal Tudo bem? estou tentando fazer uma alinhamento usando bootstrap mas não esta dando certo, alguém pode me dar um help? tenho 23 perguntas e preciso colocar 4 selects ao lado.
Obrigado

[image: Alinhamento]

Comment: **4 selectes ao lado de onde?** Se possível coloque seu HTML e se estiver usando algum CSS além do padrão do Bootstrap coloque tb que ajuda a te responder.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode usar o sistema de grid do Bootstrap para separar os blocos e depois basta adicionar os itens dentro das divs.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <p>Perguntar 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum laoreet mollis. Maecenas porttitor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <p>Perguntar 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum laoreet mollis. Maecenas porttitor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação de grids do bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/